# Get specific object in array of array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I need get a specific object in array of array in MongoDB.

I need get only the task object = [_id = ObjectId("543429a2cb38b1d83c3ff2c2")].

My document (projects):

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543428c2cb38b1d83c3ff2bd"),
    "name" : "new project", 
    "author" : ObjectId("5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b"),
    "members" : [ 
        ObjectId("5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b")
    ],
    "US" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5434297fcb38b1d83c3ff2c0"),
            "name" : "Test Story",
            "author" : ObjectId("5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b"),
            "tasks" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54342987cb38b1d83c3ff2c1"),
                    "name" : "teste3", 
                    "author" : ObjectId("5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b")
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("543429a2cb38b1d83c3ff2c2"),
                    "name" : "jklasdfa_XXX", 
                    "author" : ObjectId("5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Result expected:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("543429a2cb38b1d83c3ff2c2"),
    "name" : "jklasdfa_XXX", 
    "author" : ObjectId("5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b")
}
```

But i not getting it.
I still testing with no success:

```
db.projects.find({        
       "US.tasks._id" : ObjectId("543429a2cb38b1d83c3ff2c2")        
    }, { "US.tasks.$" : 1 })
```

I tryed with $elemMatch too, but return nothing.

```
db.projects.find({     
        "US" : {
            "tasks" : {
                $elemMatch : { 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("543429a2cb38b1d83c3ff2c2")                        
                }              
            }
        }     
})
```

Can i get ONLY my result expected using find()? If not, what and how use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an [aggregatio](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/)n for that:

```
db.projects.aggregate([{$unwind:"$US"},
                       {$unwind:"$US.tasks"},
                       {$match:{"US.tasks._id":ObjectId("543429a2cb38b1d83c3ff2c2")}},
                       {$project:{_id:0,"task":"$US.tasks"}}])
```

should return

```
{ task : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("543429a2cb38b1d83c3ff2c2"),
    "name" : "jklasdfa_XXX", 
    "author" : ObjectId("5424ac37eb0ea85d4c921f8b")
}
```

Explanation:

- `$unwind` creates a new (virtual) document for each array element
- `$match` is the query part of your find
- `$project` is similar as to project part in find i.e. it specifies the fields you want to get in the results

You might want to add a second `$match` before the `$unwind` if you know the document you are searching (look at performance metrics).

---

Edit: added a second `$unwind` since `US` is an array.

Don't know what you are doing (so realy can't tell and just sugesting) but you might want to examine if your schema (and mongodb) is ideal for your task because the document looks just like denormalized relational data probably a relational database would be better for you.